# Bootstrap 3 adding content to a "pushed" div moves other elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[print screen of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa2so.png)

[Order of the divs in different screen sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k71ia.png)

Hello. I had a situation like this in the picture. I need to reorder 3 div elements with bootstrap on a specific locations for different screen sizes.
At mobile they have to be on top of each other (by default) - this is ok.
The problem comes for tablets and laptop screens.
For Tablets and laptop screens the second div have to be placed left. So i use .col-sm-6 and .col-sm-pull-6 classes and for the first and third divs .col-sm-6 push-6. When there's no content in the divs everything is ok but when I add some text the left div pushesh the other down. How a smooth text adding can be achieved, without moving the pushed to the right div.

For the large screen div 1 is added hidden class, so the 2 and 3 become equal height, so there's no problem then also.
The problem comes only for small and medium screens.
Thanks in advance.

Here's the code also:

```css
/* =============================  
Base Element Styles
============================== */

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 line-height: 1.6;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 55px;
}

/*===============================
  Base Layout Styles
===============================*/

.navbar {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}


/* Headline */

.headline {
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

p {
 margin: 0;
}

.headline-right-top {
 height: 100px;
 background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);
}

.headline-left{

 background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
}

.headline-right-bottom {

 background: rgba(0,0,51, 0.6);
}



/*===============================
  Media Queries
===============================
```

```html
 rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name ="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0"> 
   <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <title>Newsfeed</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    Login bar
    </div> <!-- /.login-bar -->

    <div class="headline">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="headline-right-top col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 hidden-lg">
                        <div class="headline-see-all-news">
                          All News
                        </div>
                        <div class="banner-region-two">
                          Banner
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="headline-left col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-lg-pull-0">
                        <div class="headline-latest">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis culpa, ducimus molestiae velit veritatis beatae necessitatibus! Eius nihil quidem odio enim eum, eaque quis amet repellendus officiis magni impedit nesciunt.</p>
                             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis culpa, ducimus molestiae velit veritatis beatae necessitatibus! Eius nihil quidem odio enim eum, eaque quis amet repellendus officiis magni impedit nesciunt.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="headline-right-bottom col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-lg-push-0">
                        <div class="headline-oppinions">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis culpa, ducimus molestiae velit veritatis beatae necessitatibus! Eius nihil quidem odio enim eum, eaque quis amet repellendus officiis magni impedit nesciunt.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- /.row -->
            </div> <!-- /.container --> 
        </div> <!-- /.headline -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... So the issue is, in laptop / tablet, you have col-sm-6 + col-sm-6 = col-md-12 which is going to equal one full row, followed by a col-sm-6 which is always going to be a new row. Therefore when you add content to your first col-sm-6 (headline-see-all-news) it's going to push the last col-sm-6 (headline-right-bottom) down since it's on the next "row". To fix this, you can do one of two things.

1. Clearly define the right two columns as their own column in tablet / laptop. This would lead to repeated code that you have to hide/show depending on the screen size and could get messy really quick.
2. Overwrite the floats on the elements in the sm view with @media queries and remove the push/pull

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="headline-right-top col-sm-6 hidden-lg">
            <div class="headline-see-all-news">
              All News
            </div>
            <div class="banner-region-two">
              Banner
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="headline-left col-sm-6 col-lg-pull-0">
            <div class="headline-latest">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis culpa, ducimus molestiae velit veritatis beatae necessitatibus! Eius nihil quidem odio enim eum, eaque quis amet repellendus officiis magni impedit nesciunt.</p>
                 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis culpa, ducimus molestiae velit veritatis beatae necessitatibus! Eius nihil quidem odio enim eum, eaque quis amet repellendus officiis magni impedit nesciunt.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="headline-right-bottom col-sm-6 col-lg-push-0">
            <div class="headline-oppinions">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis culpa, ducimus molestiae velit veritatis beatae necessitatibus! Eius nihil quidem odio enim eum, eaque quis amet repellendus officiis magni impedit nesciunt.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /.row -->
</div> <!-- /.container -->
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px;)
{
    .headline-right-top{
        float: right !important;
    }
}
```

I've tested this with a jsfiddle and it seemed to work okay. jsfiddle doesn't seem to support media queries so I didn't link the fiddle. I'm not 100% sure if this is going to work for your situation but give it a try and let me know.

Edit: You might need a second media query to remove the float on xs devices.

```
@media (max-width: 768px;)
{
    .headline-right-top{
        float: none !important;
    }
}
```